# Selfbuild convolution function seems to be stuck indefinitely

Tags: python, convolution

I'm developing a signal convolution technique for audio processing in Python, and I've encountered an issue in which my code appears to be stuck eternally in the convolution loops.

Here is my Code

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import soundfile as sf

file1 = 'Gitarren_Sample_DI.wav'
file2 = 'Gitarren_Sample_Amp.wav'

sr, GitDI = scipy.io.wavfile.read(file1) 
sr2, GitAmp = scipy.io.wavfile.read(file2)

def todb(sampleint):
  newsample = sampleint.astype(np.float) / 2**15 #changing the values to be more suited 
  return newsample


def constep(InvIR, sampleslice):
  value = 0.
  for i in range(0, InvIR.size):
    value = value + InvIR[i]*sampleslice[i]
  return value

def convolution(ir, sample, mode):
  steplength = ir.size
  InvIR = np.flip(ir) #Für die Faltung der Signale müssen wir eines der Signale invertieren.
  samplesize = sample.size
  if (mode == 'full'):
    paddingsize = (np.round((samplesize + steplength -1)/2)).astype(int)
    paddedsample = np.pad(sample, (paddingsize, paddingsize), 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0))
    convolved = paddedsample.copy()
  
  for x in range(0, paddedsample.size):
    convolved[x] = constep(InvIR, paddedsample[x:steplength+x])
  return convolved

testir = np.zeros(24000)
testir[0] = 1
testir[-1] = 0.5 

GitDIfloat = todb(GitDI)
delaygitarre = convolution(testir, GitDI, mode = 'full')
delaygitarre /= np.max(np.abs(delaygitarre),axis=0)
plt.plot(delaygitarre)
sf.write('Delaytest.wav', delaygitarre, sr, subtype='PCM_24')
```

I've been troubleshooting this for two days and have encountered a variety of issues, the majority of which are linked to typecasting. I'm not sure whether I'm missing something obvious. Can somebody help me determine the source of the indefinite loop or offer modifications to the convolution function?

Comment: On line 12, `convolved` would appear to be a function, not something that has a `__setitem__` method. Did you  mean `convolved = paddedsample.copy()`, perhaps, forgetting to *call* a `copy` method?

Comment: (Note that if `mode != 'full'`, it seems possible for the `for` loop to be entered without `convolved` being assigned at all, which would result in a different error.)

Comment: I'm aware that the loop can be entered if the mode is not 'full', cause I'm planning to extend on the modes (i.e. valid). I'll try to actually call the copy function, too. Thanks!